# Django: How to select a limited amount of rows for each foreign key?

Tags: django

```
class Comment (models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="comments")
        title = models.TextField(max_length=256)
        comment = models.TextField(max_length=1286)
        created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

Now how do I get latest comments but limit the results to only (say 3) comments per same  user?

Here is how its done in pure SQL: [How to select a limited amount of rows for each foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590169/how-to-select-a-limited-amount-of-rows-for-each-foreign-key)

Comment: It's just Python `list( Comment.objects.filter(user=user) )[:3]` would work fine.  Why are you asking?

Comment: he wants to get all latest comments on the website, but filter them in such way that there aren't more than 3 comments from the same user

Comment: @S.Lott Not related to this question, but you probably want Comment.objects.filter(user=user)[:3] instead of list(Comment.objects.filter(user=user))[:3] when you wrap in a list it is no longer lazy loaded(loads all comments from db for that user into memory) and then gives you the first 3. without list() it will pass a limit to the query to the database which will only return 3 results. Not a big deal when there aren't many comments but it slows down quick once you get a ton of comments.

Comment: @Ken Chochrane: While true, I specifically transformed the QuerySet into a list because some folks find lists easier to understand than QuerySets.  But it's not clear what the question really means, is it?

Comment: @ S.Lott:  I tried to be clear as I could. You are welcome to edit the question if you have better phrasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, this would work:

```
Comment.objects.filter(*[
    ~Q(id__in=user.comments.order_by('-created')[3:].values_list('id', flat=True))
    for user in User.objects.all()
])
```

However, it seems like neither pythonic nor efficient way to solve the problem. (Efficiency problem could be somewhat solved by using cache, but still.)

What are you trying to achieve, anyway? You could just fetch all user's comments and use only the latest three. Assuming that your comments are ordered by `-created` field:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for comment in user.comments.all|slice:"3" %}{{ comment }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Slicing will be converted to `LIMIT` clause in SQL query, so you won't be getting all the comments anyway. Of course, there would be more that one query executed to get all the comments, so using template caching can help.

Again, this may not make sense in your case. If it doesn't, it would be better if you clarify the requirements.

#### Raw SQL

If you know how to do what you want with raw SQL ([1] may help), then you need to just find a way to put it into [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) somehow ([2] is an example of complex extra query which may give you an idea).

[1] [How to select a limited amount of rows for each foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590169/how-to-select-a-limited-amount-of-rows-for-each-foreign-key)

[2] [django's .extra(where= clauses are clobbered by table-renaming .filter(foo__in=... subselects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293874/djangos-extrawhere-clauses-are-clobbered-by-table-renaming-filterfoo-in)

Comment: I want to display all comments of the site. But no more than 3 comments per same user

Comment: Then I'd suggest to use the above template snippet inside a `{% cache %}` block. Or make a custom template tag out of the first snippet and use that, again, with template caching. However, that would be quite a lot of comments to display, depending on the number of users; perhaps you want to display a list of `n` most recent comments on the site, just making sure that there'll be _no more than_ 3 comments per same user in the list?