# Fetching the latest N items by foreign key

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to fetch the latest 3 books for each author, using a DateField for the date.
Any ideas how to do this with Django ORM or raw SQL?

```
class Author(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)                                                                                                
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=100, unique=True)                                                                                      

class Book(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, verbose_name='Author')                                                                       
    published = models.DateField('Published on', db_index=True)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, but I could help regarding raw SQL if you provide which DBMS you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705579/django-how-to-select-a-limited-amount-of-rows-for-each-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the Authors selecting 3 most recent Books for each and adding them to a global list:

```
books = []
for x in Author.objects.all():
   bookslist = Book.objects.filter(author=x).order_by('-published')[:3]
   for book in bookslist:
      books.append(book)
```